# [rtabmap_ros] Cannot mapping by RVIZ

Tags: slam, navigation, rtabmap-ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I try to use hand-held kinectv2 to record map and follow the steps in tutorials(RGB-D Hand-Held Mapping With a Kinect). Then I can record map by following steps in rtabmapviz, but fail in rviz. There is an error in "Global Status". It show "Fix Frame [map] is not exist". How do I setup?

Below are my steps:

```
$ roslaunch kinect2_bridge kinect2_bridge.launch publish_tf:=true

$ rosrun tf static_transform_publisher 0 0 0 -1.5707963267948966 0 -1.5707963267948966 camera_link kinect2_link 100

$ roslaunch rtabmap_ros rtabmap.launch rtabmap_args:="--delete_db_on_start" rviz:=true rtabmapviz:=false
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/258984/%5Brtabmap_ros%5D-cannot-mapping-by-rviz/) by [simon.xm.lee](https://answers.ros.org/users/29522/simon.xm.lee/) on ROS Answers with karma: 43 on 2017-04-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Following the [tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/rtabmap_ros/Tutorials/HandHeldMapping) for kinect2_bridge, you should use this for the third step:

```
$ roslaunch rtabmap_ros rtabmap.launch rtabmap_args:="--delete_db_on_start" rgb_topic:=/kinect2/qhd/image_color_rect depth_topic:=/kinect2/qhd/image_depth_rect camera_info_topic:=/kinect2/qhd/camera_info rviz:=true rtabmapviz:=false
```

cheers

---

Originally posted by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) with karma: 6409 on 2017-04-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [simon.xm.lee](https://answers.ros.org/users/29522/simon.xm.lee/) on 2017-04-11**:
It works. Many thanks.